# can i show what i entered input into sessions?

Tags: php

i want display all with session what i enter into input.. but only one shows .. i want display past results too with session.. here my codes;

```
<form method="post">

isim gir
<input type="text" name="isim" id="isim[]" />
<input type="submit" name="gir"  value="sözler" />

</form>

<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if(isset($_POST["gir"])){
$isim=$_POST["isim"];
echo $_SESSION["name"]=$isim;
}
?>
```

Comment: `session_start()` should be placed before any kind of output. And what do you mean by "*but only one shows*" and "*past results*"?

Comment: its something like past search keys.. but i can not enter my past results..for example i entered a word, later i entered a word too.. but only the last word display.. the past word does not display.. but i want to show the past words display too..

Comment: Put an array into the session, and push the new search string onto the array.

Comment: bro i dont know how to put array with post .. :( something like this ? ; $_SESSION['name']=array($_POST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `search_history` session variable that contains an array of all the searches.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['search_history'])) {
    $_SESSION['search_history'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['gir'])) {
    $isim = $_POST['isim'];
    $_SESSION['search_history'][] = $isim;
}
```

Comment: yes it worked but it gave error at the same time.. i put something like this ; "
if (!isset($_SESSION['search_history'])) {
    $_SESSION['search_history'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['gir'])) {
    $isim = $_POST['isim'];
    echo $_SESSION['search_history'][] = $isim;
}


for($i=0; $i<count( $_SESSION['search_history']); $i++){
echo $_SESSION['search_history'][$i];
} " and it show many times with old result..

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: BTW, you should learn to use `foreach()` to loop over an array.

Comment: bro i used foreach too.. "foreach ($_SESSION["search_history"] as $key=>$val){
echo $_SESSION["search_history"][$key]."<br />";
}" the error is, when enter last word, it display 2 times..

Comment: You mean you don't want to get duplicates if you search for the same thing twice? Use `if (!in_array($isim, $_SESSION['search_history']))` before adding the new search.

Comment: thank u bro it worked now..

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` should be placed first thing in your code, and if you want to print everything in the array of `$_SESSION` you can do:

```
echo "<pre>",print_r($_SESSION),"</pre>";
```

Comment: no bro it didnt work.. i tried it .. but it show only one result..

Comment: So if you're trying to show every result you've entered, use it as an array, and enter every result you've done as an array then you can access them all. If that makes sense.

Comment: ur answer is not helping me -.-" .. am not professional in array functions.. i tried something like this in loop.. " foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val){
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
    
    }"
but it shows again only one result..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

$sanitize_post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
if(!empty($sanitize_post)){
    $_SESSION['input'][] = $sanitize_post;
}

function reducer($acc, $val)
{
    return $acc .= $val;
}

function allUserInput()
{
    # Extract user input from session.
    if(empty($_SESSION)) return;
    foreach ($_SESSION['input'] as $key) {
        echo "<li>".array_reduce($key, 'reducer', '')."</li>";
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST">
<ul><?php echo allUserInput(); ?></ul>
<input type="text" name="isim" id="isim" />
<input type="submit" name="gir"  value="sözler" />
</form>
```

Comment: i didnt get ur answer.. there are many session.. i just want show only into one session..

Comment: Your question says to `display past results`.  Let me update it with comments

Comment: it show only last result not past results ..

Comment: I modified it to show all user input

Comment: error "Warning: array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in index.php on line 52"

Comment: You'll need to restart your server to start a new session. The error is as a result of past data stored in the $_SESSION array that is not consistent with the new handling

Comment: Possibly temporarily add a call to `session_destroy()` and remove it.